# DFP in BlackBerry with simple url tags not loading the ad image

Tags: blackberry, blackberry-jde, google-dfp

From the DFP publishers doc I read that we can show DFP ads in BlackBerry with the help of Simple url tags. I am trying to add a DFP ad to a project which already builds in java. Since simple url tags are possible to show DFP ads in blackberry, I choose the for iphone and android without using the admob sdks. And i successfully implemented the DFP with simple url tags in Android and iPhone with the help of docs from these sites:
[Simple url tags for mobile](https://support.google.com/dfp_sb/answer/2472143?hl=en)
[Serve ads in a non javascript environment](https://support.google.com/dfp_premium/answer/1638620)

But in while trying DFP in BlackBerry I was not able to show the ad. Then I tried to load an image from a url with the help of [Blackberry WebBitmapField](http://www.coderholic.com/blackberry-webbitmapfield/), but in the begining I was stuck loading the image. Then i found out from [Creating a BlackBerry HTTP Connection – Tutorial](http://developerlife.com/tutorials/?p=884) that there are a number of scenarios for loading a URL with a Http connection in BlackBerry.

So I load an image from server by appending **;interface=wifi** with the url. The same thing i tried to load the DFP ad by appending **;interface=wifi**, but it was not successful. 
1. Do any one tried simple url tags in blackberry?
2. Is there is anything to append with the url for loading DFP ads with simple url tags in blackberry?
3. While loading an image from the google server, is there need to append any more parameters in blackberry?

Note:Please inform if there is any code needed.

Comment: Its always better to show some code snippets if you have tried something.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the case of BlackBerry the response of the url was directing to another location. Its kind of status code error 302 something. So i took the redirecting url from the Http response header and load the image.